# AngularJS Nested jQuery UI Sortables with Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, angularjs

I've got a AngularJS directive that hooks up sortables.

I'm trying to create a directive that will allow me to drag and drop new items into a sortable.  If that item is a 'section' it should allow further drag and drops into it recursively.  The section inits a sortable itself and I attempt to connect the sortables.  Problem is it never connects...  I've built similar demos with jqueryUI alone so I know that its possible, my angular implementation is probably just messing something up.  Any ideas?

sortable directive:

```
app.constant('sortableConfig', {
    connectWith: '.sortables'
});

app.directive('sortable', ['$timeout','sortableConfig', function ($timeout, sortableConfig) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            options: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            var ngModel = $scope.ngModel;

            var options = angular.extend(sortableConfig, 
                    $scope.$eval($attributes.options)),
                sortableIn = 0;

            console.log(ngModel)

            options.start = function(e, ui) {
                // Save position of dragged item
                ui.item.sortable = { index: ui.item.index() };
            };

            options.update = function(e, ui) {
                // For some reason the reference to ngModel in stop() is wrong
                ui.item.sortable.resort = ngModel;
            };

            options.receive = function(e, ui) {
                sortableIn = 1;
                ui.item.sortable.relocate = true;
                // added item to array into correct position and set up flag
                ngModel.splice(ui.item.index(), 0, ui.item.sortable.moved);
            };

            options.remove = function(e, ui) {
                // copy data into item
                if (ngModel.length === 1) {
                    ui.item.sortable.moved = ngModel.splice(0, 1)[0];
                } else {
                    ui.item.sortable.moved =  ngModel.splice(ui.item.sortable.index, 1)[0];
                }
            };

            options.over = function(e, ui) {
                sortableIn = 1;
            };

            options.out = function(e, ui) {
                sortableIn = 0;
            };

            options.beforeStop = function(e, ui) {
                // http://snipplr.com/view/49923/
                if (sortableIn == 0) { 
                    console.log('REMOVE!', ui.item.sortable.resort)
                    //ui.item.remove(); 
                    //ngModel.splice(ui.item.index(), 1);
                }
            };

            options.stop = function(e, ui) {
                // digest all prepared changes
                if (ui.item.sortable.resort && !ui.item.sortable.relocate) {
                    // Fetch saved and current position of dropped element
                    var end, start;
                    start = ui.item.sortable.index;
                    end = ui.item.index();

                    // Reorder array and apply change to scope
                    ui.item.sortable.resort.splice(
                        end, 0, ui.item.sortable.resort.splice(start, 1)[0]);
                }
            };

            $timeout(function(){
                console.log(options)
                $element.sortable(options);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

sortable template:

```
 <ul sortable class="sortable" ng-model="ngModel">
<li class="pull-left" ng-repeat="item in ngModel" ng-model="item" ng-style="drawLayout(item)">
    <div ng-if="isField(item)"
         class="btn btn-info btn-draggable layout-field"
         ng-click="showDetails(item)">{{item.name}}</div>

    <div droppable 
         ng-model="item.children"
         dropped="layoutDropped(dragModel, dropModel)" 
         ng-if="item.typeOf == 'section'"
         class="panel panel-default layout-section">

        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="showDetails(item)">
            {{item.name}}
            <div ng-show="item.helpTextOpt != 'none'">
                <hr />
                <p>{{item.helpText}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" onload="ngModel=item.children"
             ng-include="'views/app-builder/layout.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: suggest using nested sortable plugin which is an extension of jQuery UI sortable. A demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: Ya, found a few ... any you would recommend?

Comment: only know of one...never had problems with it, haven't used for long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution that uses jQueryUI's sortable and can hook into draggable and droppable.  [Full details here](https://gist.github.com/amcdnl/7537096#file-useage-md)

Answer (score 2):

You could reference the code of Angular-NestedSortable(https://github.com/JimLiu/Angular-NestedSortable).
An Angularjs ui component that can sort nested lists and bind data, and it dosen't need to depend on jQuery.